# Get a boolean on the existence of a reactive value in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

**Situation**

I would like to use multiple reactive values (in example ab and cd) to create a new one (in example merge).
It is possible that only some are available (in example ab or cd or both), because not every category available needs to be calculated.
The idea is to check for the existence of the according reactive value and, depending on it, add or skip the according category.

**Approaches not working**

Proposed methods for checking/validating reactive values include `req()`, `validate()`, `need()` and `isTruthy()`, but these generate an error, not an (to my knowledge) usable return like TRUE or FALSE. `exists()` seems not to be able to handle an non-existing reactive value, even though I would think it would be the ideal function (giving TRUE or FALSE depending on the existence of a variable).
**Edit 1**: `is.null()` does not work either. When the according reactive value is not existent yet, the function is exited as with the other approaches. To clarify: It seems each time a non-existent reactive value is called the function is exited. **Edit 1**

**Question**

Is there a possibility to check for the existence of a reactive value in shiny, with result, not an error (or an idea for a workaround)?

Please see the code, in this example with `exists()`.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  # inputs first reactive value
  sliderInput("a",
              "a",
              1, 10, 2 ,1),
  sliderInput("b",
              "b",
              1, 10, 4 ,1),
  # calculate first reactive value
  actionButton("ab", "calc a + b"),

  # inputs second reactive value
  sliderInput("c",
              "c",
              1, 10, 6 ,1),
  sliderInput("d",
              "d",
              1, 10, 8 ,1),
  # calculate second reactive value
  actionButton("cd", "calc c + d"),

  # outputs
  verbatimTextOutput("result_ab"),
  verbatimTextOutput("result_cd"),
  verbatimTextOutput("result_merge")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # outputs
  output$result_ab <- renderPrint(ab())
  output$result_cd <- renderPrint(cd())
  output$result_merge <- renderPrint(merge())
  
  # calculations 
  ab <- eventReactive(input$ab,{
    ab <- input$a + input$b
    ab
  })
  
  cd <- eventReactive(input$cd,{
    cd <- input$c + input$d
    cd
  })
  
  # merge of existing values
  merge <- reactive({
    merge <- c() # empty vector to be filled up
    
    if(exists(ab())){
      merge <- c(merge, ab())
    }

    if(exists(cd())){
      merge <- c(merge, cd())
    }

    merge
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the correct wording, but roughly speaking, since `merge()` depends on `ab()` and `cd()`, it is "invalidated" (it does not run) as long as `ab()` or `cd()` do not "exist". At least this is what I think.

You can use reactive values and observers instead:

```server
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # inputs first reactive value
  sliderInput("a",
              "a",
              1, 10, 2 ,1),
  sliderInput("b",
              "b",
              1, 10, 4 ,1),
  # calculate first reactive value
  actionButton("ab", "calc a + b"),

  # inputs second reactive value
  sliderInput("c",
              "c",
              1, 10, 6 ,1),
  sliderInput("d",
              "d",
              1, 10, 8 ,1),
  # calculate second reactive value
  actionButton("cd", "calc c + d"),

  # outputs
  verbatimTextOutput("result_ab"),
  verbatimTextOutput("result_cd"),
  verbatimTextOutput("result_merge")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # outputs
  output$result_ab <- renderPrint(ab())
  output$result_cd <- renderPrint(cd())
  output$result_merge <- renderPrint(merge())
  
  # calculations 
  ab <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  cd <- reactiveVal(NULL)

  observeEvent(input$ab,{
    ab(input$a + input$b)
  })  
  observeEvent(input$cd,{
    cd(input$c + input$d)
  })
  
  # merge of existing values
  merge <- reactive({
    merge <- c() # empty vector to be filled up
    if(!is.null(ab())){
      merge <- ab()
    }
    if(!is.null(cd())){
      merge <- c(merge, cd())
    }
    merge
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Ah, yes, exactly. Thank you, that works. I get it. I thought it is like "invalidated", thats why I wanted to check whether it exists or not avoid that problem. But that seems not to be possible. Anyways, the solution works for me perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your `reactive` is not expected to return `NULL` at some point, you can check if the return value of a `reactive` is not `NULL`:

```
 merge <- reactive({
    merge <- c() # empty vector to be filled up
    
    if(!is.null(ab())){
      merge <- c(merge, ab())
    }
    
    if(!is.null(cd())){
      merge <- c(merge, cd())
    }
    
    merge
  })
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. is.null() was actually my first try, I forgot to mention. Doesn't work either. I edited the question to include it.

Comment: Also not with your MRE? For me it seems to work, or did I miss something?

Comment: No, for me it doesn't work. If I calculate just one of them, the desired result for the merge would be just that one element. But I just get nothing as merge. Only if all reactivates are available the merge is available. Via debug, it works until I come to a point where a non-existent reactive is used. At that point the "merge" is exited straight, without any return.